# scala nested for/yield generator to extract substring

Tags: scala, for-loop, syntax, nested, yield

I am new to scala. Pls be gentle. My problem for the moment is the syntax error. 
(But my ultimate goal is to print each group of 3 characters from every string in the list...now i am merely printing the first 3 characters of every string)

```
def do_stuff():Unit = {
  val s =  List[String]("abc", "fds", "654444654")

  for {
    i <- s.indices
    r <- 0 to s(i).length by 3
    println(s(i).substring(0,3))
  } yield {s(i)}
}

do_stuff()
```

i am getting this error. it is syntax related, but i dont undersatnd..

> Error:(12, 18) ')' expected but '.' found.
>       println(s(i).substring(0,3))

Comment: Can you give us an output example?

Comment: Look at `grouped` - it may be you want. `for {r <- s; t <- r.grouped(3)} yield t` (untested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code doesn't compile because in a for-comprehension, you can't just put a print statement, you always need an assignment, in this case, a dummy one can solve your porblem.

```
_ = println(s(i).substring(0,3))
```

EDIT

If you want the combination of 3 elements in every String you can use combinations method from collections.

```
List("abc", "fds", "654444654").flatMap(_.combinations(3).toList)
```

Comment: abc
abc
fds
fds
654
654
654
654 This is the output of the above code I am getting in scala REPL. The question clearly states that all 3 charactor substrings from each string of the list given is required..Is n't it?

Comment: sorry, I focused on the compilation problem and didn't realize that the algorithm wasn't working

Comment: I think this still gives wrong output.scala> List("abc", "fds", "654444654").flatMap(_.combinations(3).toList)
res3: List[String] = List(abc, fds, 665, 664, 655, 654, 644, 554, 544, 444) I think it should be consecutive substrings he meant. Moreover he wants to use for conprehension

Comment: @RAGHHURAAMM, why did you erase your answer? you had a point.

Comment: @user3600237, Because your requirement is different, I deleted it. may be it is of little use to you  as you are concerned with the reason for the compilation error, you made as per your comment on the answer. But I tried to give you with corrected code that works as per your requirement.

Comment: apologies. i am new to stack overflow. i didnt realize it was unclear. you gave the answer using for/yield. pls put it back.

Comment: `def do_stuff():Unit = {
   val s =  List[String]("abc", "fds", "654444654")
   val p = for(s1<-s;i<-0 to s1.size-3) yield{s1.substring(i,i+3)}
   p.foreach(println)
 }`